# Make a matrix of plots with row and column titles

Tags: r, plot

Using the `par(mfrow = c(m,n))` command I can easily make a matrix of plots with `m` rows and `n` columns.

In special cases, there is a pattern in the plots, such that all the plots in each column share an important attribute, and all the plots in each row share a different important attribute.  All such information can be included in the title of each of the `m*n` plots individually, but this is obviously repetitive.

Is there a convenient way to append column names (only above the top row of plots) and row names (only to the left of the left column of plots) in such a grid?

**Best solution so far**: Use the `text()` command to place text outside of the left-and-top plots.  But this is pretty unsatisfactory, as it requires many separate commands, and tweaking arguments such as `srt = 90` to make the text vertical on the left margin, and using `xpd = NA` inside of `par()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lattice and ggplot2 packages have tools for creating multiple plots in a grid.  They may speed up your entire process if they apply to what you want to do.

```
library(lattice)

splom( ~ iris[,1:4], data=iris, groups=Species )
xyplot( mpg ~ wt | factor(cyl)*factor(am), data=mtcars )

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(am ~ cyl)
```

Using base graphics you can start by setting an outer margin, see the `oma` argument to the `par` command, then use the `mtext` function to write the text into the outer margin for your labels.

```
par( oma=c(0,6,6,0), mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(2,2,1,1)+0.1 )
with(iris, plot(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width, ann=FALSE))
mtext( 'Width', side=3, line=2, at=grconvertX(0.5,'npc','nic'), outer=TRUE )
mtext( 'Width', side=2, line=2, at=grconvertY(0.5,'npc','nic'), outer=TRUE )
mtext( 'Sepal', side=3, line=4, outer=TRUE, cex=2 )
mtext( 'Petal', side=2, line=4, outer=TRUE, cex=2 )
with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, ann=FALSE))
mtext( 'Length', side=3, line=2, at=grconvertX(0.5,'npc','nic'), outer=TRUE )
with(iris, plot(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, ann=FALSE))
mtext( 'Length', side=2, line=2, at=grconvertY(0.5, 'npc','nic'), outer=TRUE )
with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, ann=FALSE))
```

Comment: Your third answer is the most appealing to me, as it looks flexible. It looks like the crucial elements are the `oma` argument in `par()`, the `mtext` function and its `outer` argument, and `grconvertX/Y`. I still hope that `R` developers find a more streamlined interface, some kind of `metapar()`.

Comment: @zkurtz, You can always write a function yourself to do what you want.  If it is useful enough to other people then put it in a package, if it is useful enough then it may end up in the regular R eventually.  It is not obvious to me how the function would work that would give you the flexibility and be simpler than doing it by hand (the 1st 2 options give the simplicity, and other tools also give the simplicity, but you seem to want the flexibility).